# Как узнать крайнюю левую позицию sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Как у знать крайнюю левую позицию элемента при после его  перемещения у плагина jquery UI sorttable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После перемещения элемента в момент его отпускания *jQuery UI Sortable* генерирует событие [`beforeStop`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-beforeStop).
Обработчик этого события в качестве второго аргумента принимает специальный объект `ui`. Этот объект, помимо всего прочего, содержит свойства:

- `offset` — положение перетаскиваемого элемента относительно документа
- `position` — положение элемента относительно родительского элемента

Соответственно, крайняя левая позицию относительно документа `ui.offset.left`, крайняя левая позицию относительно родителя `ui.position.left`.

<sub>Полный код примера</sub>

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
  beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('offset.left: ' + ui.offset.left, 'position.left: ' + ui.position.left)
  }
});
```

```css
#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#sortable li {
  padding: 0.4em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: лучше все же событие beforeStop использовать, а не sort. Sort очень часто происходит.

Comment: @Sergalas событие `sort` используют, когда нужно определить, куда перемещается элемент, `beforeStop` — где его кинули. Если в вопросе имеется в виду второе, то тогда он (вопрос) сформулирован двусмысленно, так как "при его перемещении" можно понять как "во время перемещения". Если мой ответ неправильный, то добавьте свой правильный. Или исправьте свой вопрос, уберите двусмысленность, я исправлю ответ.

Comment: я разве спрашивал узнать позицию элемента в момент его движения? Он исправил и подтвердил потому что в главном вы то правы :)